# why do I get “permission denied” when trying to start tomcat and write std out to a text file?

Tags: linux, unix, console, sudo

I'm trying to start tomcat in such a way that it writes standard out to a text file.

I'm do this but I get a permission denied.  Why is that?

```
[rob@machine1 bin]$ pwd
/usr/lib64/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/bin
[rob@machine1 bin]$ sudo ./startup.sh > console.log 2<&1
bash: console.log: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirections are done by the current shell, which does not have sudo rights. When you want to write to console.log, you run sudo on a shell that can in turn do redirections:

```
sudo sh -c './startup.sh > console.log 2>&1'
```

Remarks:
I switched the direction of `2<&1` into `2>&1`.
You might want to include the redirections in your own startup script.